# How get element's child and then child's src

Tags: javascript, getattribute

Hope somebody can help with this:

[My Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/qy04bm3b/)

1. How can I get element's child with exact tag name (in this case `img`)?
2. How can I get this child's attribute?

Next doesn't work:

```
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
var imgElement = banner.getElementsByTagName('img');
var imgSrc = imgElement.getAttribute('src');
```

Last line returns `imgElement.getAttribute is not a function`. I guess it's because of second line, where I get `object HTMLCollection`...But why I got this and what I have to do to get what I want?

Thanx a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: `var imgElement = banner.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an HTMLCollection, so get the first element in the array and then its src

```
var imgSrc = imgElement[0].getAttribute('src');
```

```js
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
var imgElement = banner.getElementsByTagName('img');
var imgSrc = imgElement[0].getAttribute('src');
alert(imgSrc);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="banner">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="kitten" />
</a>
```

Another solution is to use querySelector(will be little slower)

```
var imgElement = document.querySelector('#banner img');
var imgSrc = imgElement.getAttribute('src');
alert(imgSrc);
```

```js
var imgElement = document.querySelector('#banner img');
var imgSrc = imgElement.getAttribute('src');
alert(imgSrc);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="banner">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="kitten" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative solution using children.

```js
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
var childImg = banner.children[0];
var imgSrc = childImg.getAttribute('src');
alert(imgSrc);
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: Thank you :) But I chose for my self Arun P Johny's second solution. Easier to understand and less to write :) But anyway thanx!